# Rails - any plugin/gem for creating calendars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, jquery-plugins, rubygems, calendar

I was trying to find a gem or plugin that had a cool looking calendar control.
Is there anything that someone can recommend?

Is there a way to display a set from 2 different months like dec. 11 - jan. 11?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [later_dude](https://github.com/clemens/later_dude) . It's Rails3 month calendar helper with great customizability and I18n support.